# unable to render pdf

Tags: android, pdf

a problem occurred when trying to render pdf pages, i am using pdfviewer library(obtained from https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library).

I stored my pdfs into the device's internal storage. When I tried to display the pdf but it only shows the interface with a blank white page in the area where the pdf is supposed to be displayed. Strangely, it also shows the page number as well.

A statement in logcat states that: "11-01 11:30:37.240: E/AWTPDF.pdfimage(8675): image too large (OutOfMemoryError)"

This is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pes6w.png

Comment: Have you tried with any smaller PDF?

Comment: I tried one with 500KB, it displays some fuzzy gray image.

Comment: May be it is a known issue, check it out; https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library/issues/1

Comment: @Mudassir thank you for the link but I have checked and I couldn't find an issue similar to mine.

Comment: @Jolene The Small PDF is working in my case.

Comment: Are you passing the file Name to the wrong activity maybe? - It has to be passed to the activity in the Jar and not to the locally created activity you have created

Comment: check this http://code.google.com/p/apv/ for mupdf library for pdf rendering

Comment: @Jolene I think  [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/1482845) will help you.