# Convert Pdf page to Image using DroidText in android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-droidtext

I'm trying to use `droidText` [Link here](http://code.google.com/p/droidtext/wiki/GettingStarted) to convert an PDF page to an Image (to show in `ImageView`! However, I can't find any solution for this with `droidText` lib after 2 day of google searching! So I want to ask for a help to solve this problem? Anyone does it before? Can you show me some examples? Thanks!

Comment: hold on!!! u want to convert a pdf page to image or an view(in android) to image? just clarify... if second one then yes I have done and made pdf successfully using droidtext.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/2027232

Answer (score 0):

I Foud a Link (it is not related  to droitext), you can use it to build your solution

[http://www.jpedal.org/gplSrc/org/jpedal/examples/images/ConvertPagesToImages.java.html?_*hstc=123926613.cadb52490e653b75bf4281c606218039.1356089256893.1356089256893.1356089256893.1&*_hssc=123926613.1.1356089256893]](http://www.jpedal.org/gplSrc/org/jpedal/examples/images/ConvertPagesToImages.java.html?__hstc=123926613.cadb52490e653b75bf4281c606218039.1356089256893.1356089256893.1356089256893.1&__hssc=123926613.1.1356089256893%5D)

you can have a look on the function
extractPageAsImage