# Open PDF in specific Layout in Activity

Tags: java, android, pdf

We have a android application which can open PDF files from sd card

List of files shown in a ListView. User selected file will be open in Adobe reader activity i am using this code to open pdf file

```
     intent.setPackage("com.adobe.reader");
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile( file ), "application/pdf");
     startActivity(intent);
```

Now problem is that when i open pdf file it will open in a new Activity. I want to open this pdf file in my own activity specific layout for example i want to open this pdf file in my Scroll view  some thing  like that

```
          scrollview.addview(PDFView);
```

I have many view on my activity i want to open pdf file in a specific view. Is it Possible with Adobe Reader without using any libraray like MUPDF or APV.  Or is there any PDF Reader jar available open source which suppport android Delvik. Because i knwo JReble and some other java PDF librarires are avaible but it have no support for Delvik they support only JVM Any Suggestion or idea will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet would be my answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/2027232 if you want it for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to open inside a view in your own application, you'll have to use a pdf library.  There is no equivalent to OLE or COM in Android where you can embed view from other apks.  I know a few decent ones-  Qoppa, Raede, and PDFTron.  All of them are expensive.