# PDF activity in android?

Tags: android, pdf, sdk

I am using the library hosted on this site jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library to display a PDF within my own application.

However the PDF files I have to use (provided by my client) don't render well using this library, to begin with the text is rendered backwards, and most of the 2D drawings (text boxes and the like) are shown cut-off, or not shown at all.

Does anyone know if there is a better library for accomplishing this task? I have searched for a while but every library I found was on a GPL license, the project Im developing is private and delivering source code is not an option.

Is there a "standard" way to show a PDF, inside app, in Android?

Comment: "Is there a "standard" way to show a PDF, inside app, in Android?" -- the standard thing to do is to launch a third-party PDF viewer, by an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`.

Comment: I know of this way but for my client that's our last option

Comment: Check this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630382/how-to-enable-pinch-zoom-on-a-web-view-loading-a-url-with-pdfandroid Option described in here might help you.