# Programming Android search button to search within a pdf (like Ctrl-F traditionally does)

Tags: android, search, pdf

I am currently creating an android app based on code in this question

[Need help to convert a Pdf page into Bitmap in Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java/16294833#16294833)

It is meant to go out and grab image files of maps with containing data on them (PDF). 
From the computer, I can hit Ctrl+F to search the data within the file. 
I was wondering if this was possible to program an android search button on click to do the Ctrl+F function on the PDF in the mobile device? If so, please post the code or a demonstration on how to do that.

Comment: What are you using to display the PDF?

Comment: here is the the code ill be using to display the files. stackoverflow.com/a/16294833/2027232

Answer (score 1):

You are welcome to write your own PDF viewing app. You are welcome to have that app support a hardware keyboard doing a search via `Ctrl`-`F`. You are welcome to have that app offer support for using a search button (on the few devices that have one) for doing a search as well.

Comment: I don't believe there's any intention to trigger this via Ctrl-F (though that would be nice if someone has a bluetooth keyboard) but rather to make the search button search within the PDF comparably to how Ctrl-F works in a typical desktop PDF viewer.