# getting UnsupportedOperationException: do not show image converting pdf to image in Android

Tags: android, pdf

I want to get first pdf page in image format, i'm using PdfViewer.jar and this is my code

```
private void pdfLoadImages()
{
    try
    {
        // run async
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
                {
                    // create and show a progress dialog
                    ProgressDialog progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "", "Opening...");

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
                    {
                        //after async close progress dialog
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            // select a document and get bytes
                            File file = new File(librosPdfRuta[0]);
                            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
                            FileChannel channel = raf.getChannel();
                            ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.NEW(channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, channel.size()));
                            raf.close();
                            // create a pdf doc
                            PDFFile pdf = new PDFFile(bb);
                            //Get the first page from the pdf doc
                            PDFPage PDFpage = pdf.getPage(1, true);
                            //create a scaling value according to the WebView Width
                            //final float scale = 1000 / PDFpage.getWidth() * 0.95f;
                            //convert the page into a bitmap with a scaling value
                            float scale = 1;
                            Bitmap page = PDFpage.getImage((int)(PDFpage.getWidth() * scale), (int)(PDFpage.getHeight() * scale), null, true, true);

                            guardarBytes(getBytes(page));


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Log.d("CounterA", e.toString());
                    }
                        return null;
                    }
                }.execute();
                System.gc();// run GC
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("error", e.toString());
    }
}
```

I get this code from [Need help to convert a Pdf page into Bitmap in Android Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java)

But I always get this error

```
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616): do not show images
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: do not show images
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.PDFImage.getImage(PDFImage.java:223)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.drawImage(PDFRenderer.java:374)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.PDFImageCmd.execute(PDFPage.java:654)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.PDFRenderer.iterate(PDFRenderer.java:674)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.run(BaseWatchable.java:101)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.execute(BaseWatchable.java:263)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.BaseWatchable.go(BaseWatchable.java:197)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.sun.pdfview.PDFPage.getImage(PDFPage.java:237)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.bookreader.LibrosDispositivo$1.doInBackground(LibrosDispositivo.java:347)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at com.bookreader.LibrosDispositivo$1.doInBackground(LibrosDispositivo.java:1)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-22 13:51:37.232: E/APV.PDFRenderer(30616):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

How can I solve it? Thank you very much

Comment: Вы смогли решить проблему? Я сейчас с ней столкнулся

Answer (score -1):

AsyncTask was made with 3 parametres. in your case 
android.os.AsyncTask.
Here Params and Result are input and output from ui thread.
You should not use any functions which are using ui thread inside doInBackground() method.
Try to return Bitmap from doInBachround() and onPostExecute drow it.

Comment: You are right, but i'm not drawing the bitmap, I only want to obtain it and I get that error, any solution?

Comment: try to close raf after getting PDFPage