# pdf view in gridview android

Tags: android, pdf, gridview

I would like to ask advise if displaying pdf inside gridview instead of image is possible. I have tried to display list of websites in gridview using webview. Now, I want to make it a list of pdf files inside gridview. Normally same with if you open your folder in your linux laptop and have the thumbnails of your pdf, things like that. I want to achieve that in my application. I would really appreciate any of your advice, no codes needed cause i will handle it my self. I just want to have some theories. thanks and HAPPY NEW YEAR GUYS

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're going to have to is convert the pdf's into a bitmap first, then load into an ImageView, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java) and also look into other pdf rendering libraries for Android.

Comment: thanks for that insight sir, how ever I have think that may be it would be easier to dislay them in list view. and just create a layout that would support the viewing of the pdf?how that sounds?

Comment: not much difference between listview and gridview, you still have to convert to bitmap.