# How to convert pdf to png in Android?

Tags: android, image, pdf, png

A little problem i'm having right now with my  app.
I've found solutions in Java, using Ghost4J... But it uses java.awt.Image, that I can't import in Android. I java, I have something like that :

```
PDFDocument document = new PDFDocument();
                document.load(file);

                SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
                renderer.setResolution();

                List<Image> images = renderer.render(document);
                for (int i = 0; i < images.size(); i++) {
                    ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) images.get(i), "png", new File((i + 1) + ".png"));
                }
```

So, my problem is that I have a picture in pdf format, and I need to convert it in png, cause I use a printer that can't handle pdf...

Hope you guys, will find a way...
Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english!

Comment: Simply take a screenshot of your current View.

Comment: I don't think that the screenshot is what he wants. Imagine that the user zoom on particular zone in the PDF. if he takes a screenshot, his image will cover only the active zone and not all the page

Answer (score 2):

[PdfRenderer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.html) is what you are looking for. More precisely: the method render in the [PdfRender.Page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfRenderer.Page.html) class.

```
void    render(Bitmap destination, Rect destClip, Matrix transform, int renderMode)
```

it runders the PDF page to a bitmap. And then from bitmap to PNG use the method [bitmap.compress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, didn't know that... But it appears that it needs api 21, my current min in 15... Is there a way for earlier versions?
Thx

Comment: There is a 2012 topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java