# Convert A PDF file into a image in XamarinForms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have a File with the path of .PDF file location like,

```
Java.IO.File file=new Java.IO.File(/storage/emulated/0/Pdffolder/xyz.pdf)
```

How to convert this file into an `Image` in `xamarin` forms.
   Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the guides on [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in order to get better answers.

Comment: This question is duplicated, please read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8814758/need-help-to-convert-a-pdf-page-into-bitmap-in-android-java